# Dataview RowFilter escape invalid characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable, dataview

Does any one have a handy ready to use method to escape wildcards, invalid characters in the string to be assigned to `RowFilter` for a `DataView` in C#. The rules somewhat are like below

```
If a column name contains any of these special characters ~ ( ) # \ / = > < + - * % & | ^ ' " 

[ ], you must enclose the column name within square brackets [ ]. If a column name contains 

right bracket ] or backslash \, escape it with backslash (\] or \\).
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work based on the specs outlined in a bit more detail found [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckValue("fefe[][]12#");
    CheckValue("abvds");
    CheckValue("#");
    CheckValue(@"[][][][][]\\\\\][]");
    CheckValue("^^^efewfew[[]");
}

public static string CheckValue(string value)
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(value);

    string pattern = @"([-\]\[<>\?\*\\\""/\|\~\(\)\#/=><+\%&\^\'])";

    Regex expression = new Regex(pattern);

    if (expression.IsMatch(value))
    {
        sBuilder.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        sBuilder.Replace("]", @"\]");
        sBuilder.Insert(0, "[");
        sBuilder.Append("]");
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

I tossed it into a web page I was looking at so disregard the Page_Load and of course test however you would like.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry but nope, did you try something like below as input `Status = 'TRUE'`

Comment: Based on how I understood the author's question it was correct.  What they really wanted was the last right bracket to not be escaped if it was added as part of the name. This article http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ helped me better understand what they wanted.  I updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Also note that the quickwatch or watch window will show the value escaped.  If you click on the magnifying glass on text visualizer you will see the actual output.  'TRUE' now returns as ['TRUE']

Comment: Status = 'TRUE' returns as [Status = 'TRUE'] and I just realized you were the author :)  Anyway, give this a shot and if this doesn't do what you had in mind help me understand what the problem is and ill fix it up for ya.